# Buffer dtype cannot be buffer in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Im trying to convert a bilateral filter I wrote to run on my GPU via numba but I can't seem to get it to work! Im getting the error

`TypeError: Buffer dtype cannot be buffer, have dtype: array(float64, 2d, A)`

from the following code.

```
 @vectorize([(float64[:,:], float64[:,:])], target='cuda')
def apply_filter(img, filteredImage):

    imh, imw = img.shape[:2]
    hd = int((diameter - 1) / 2)

    for h in range(hd, imh - hd):
        for w in range(hd, imw - hd):
            Wp = 0
            filteredPixel = 0
            radius = diameter // 2
            for x in range(0, diameter):
                for y in range(0, diameter):

                    currentX = w - (radius - x)
                    cureentY = h - (radius - y)

                    intensityDifferent = img[currentX][cureentY] - img[w][h]
                    intensity = (1.0/ (2 * math.pi * (sIntesity ** 2))* math.exp(-(intensityDifferent ** 2) / (2 * sIntesity ** 2)))
                    foo = (currentX - w) ** 2 + (cureentY - h) ** 2
                    distance = cmath.sqrt(foo)
                    smoothing = (1.0 / (2 * math.pi * (sSpace ** 2))) * math.exp( -(distance.real ** 2) / (2 * sSpace ** 2))
                    weight = intensity * smoothing
                    filteredPixel += img[currentX][cureentY] * weight
                    Wp += weight

            filteredImage[h][w] = int(round(filteredPixel / Wp))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = cv2.imread("messy2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    src = src.astype(np.float64)
    filtered_image_own = np.zeros(src.shape)
    apply_filter(src, filtered_image_own)
    filtered_image_own = filtered_image_own.astype(np.uint8) 
    cv2.imwrite("filtered_image4.png", filtered_image_own)
```

I've looked around and haven't found anything useless except that this error might be because a list is passed in? But both of my arguments are 2D arrays and the signature should be correct for that. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass in arrays or take array outputs, it's better to use `guvectorize()`.
Check it out at [Numba docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/vectorize.html#guvectorize) or [this blog](https://tobiasraabe.github.io/blog/numba-vectorize-and-guvectorize.html) for a detailed account of usage.

Comment: Thanks that blog is really helpful! I switched over to using a guvectorize but Im having trouble finding how to describe the input output layout (n) -> (n) thing. I saw that the numba docs briefly describes () for scalars and (n) for 1d arrays but I don't know how to describe 2d arrays. Do you have anything for that?

Comment: Well, for 2D arrays you'd write (m,n): pretty intuitive!